# c pointers and pointers to arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I came across this piece of code on the net.I simply dont understand whats going on here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    int arr [ ][3] = {{11,12,13}, {21,22,23},{31,32,33},{41,42,43},{51,52,53}};
    int I , j ;
    int  *p ,  (*q) [3], *r ;
    p = (int *) arr ;
    q = arr;
    r = (int *) q ;
    printf ("  %u  %u  %d  %d  %d  %d \n  ", p, q, *p, *(r), *(r+1), *(r+2));
    p++ ;
    q++ ;
    r = (int *) q ;
    printf ("  %u  %u  %d  %d  %d  %d \n  ", p, q, *p, *(r), *(r+1), *(r+2));
}
```

i understand that p and r are pointers,q is a pointer to an array,but what does p = (int *) arr ; mean?What purpose does this statement serve?

Comment: `p = (int *) arr;` is casting the array address to `p`. The cast is necessary because they have different levels of indirection.

Comment: Arr is not a pointer, it's a sequence of values. In fact a bidimensional array. P is set to point on the first element of this array (where the values are stored). This code allows you to see how the values of a bidimensional array are stored in memory.

Comment: That is why I said "array address", but my MSVC compiler thinks it's a pointer when I remove the cast. `warning C4047: '=' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (*)[3]'`

Comment: @WeatherVane `arr` decays to a pointer in this situation, but it is a pointer of incompatible type to `int *`

Answer (score 1):

`arr` in expressions is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. As an element of `arr` has type `int[3]` then `arr` is converted to `int ( * )[3]`

And the following code snippet demonstrates this implicit conversion

```
int  (*q) [3];

q = arr;
```

Statement

```
 p = (int *) arr;
```

means reinterpretation of `arr`that has type int ( * )[3] after the conversion like `int *`.

`( int * )` before `arr` denotes so-called casting that is reinterpretation.

Now the memory occupied by two-dimensional array `arr` is reinterpreted as a memory occupied by one-dimensional array having type `int [15]` and `p` points to the first element of this imaginary array.